# Get tbody next to one below the current tbody

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint table and would like to get the tbody of the table right one below the tbody with groupstring.

Sample table

```
<tbody groupstring=“%3B%23Application%3B%23”>
<tr><td> : Application </td></tr></tbody>
<tbody></tbody>
<tbody>
<tr><td><a href=“https://link1.com”>Link 1</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href=“https://link3.com”>Link 3</a></td></tr>
</tbody>
```

I will be getting another link Link2 from Json and dynamically inserting it between Link1 and Link3 with Jquery

```
var addRow=function(url,displayName){
Var counter=0;
$(‘tbody[groupstring=“%3B%23Application%3B%23”]’).closest(‘tbody’).find(‘td’).each(function(){
counter++;
If($(this).find(‘td:eq(0)’).text() > displayName){
$(this).before(makeRow(url,displayName));
} else {
If($(this).find(‘td:eq(0)’).text() === displayName){
$(this).html(makeRow(url,displayName));
Return false;
}}
If($(this).closest(‘table’).find(‘td.md-vb2’).length === counter){
$(this).parent().after(makeRow(url,displayName));
} 
});
};

Var makeRow = function(url,displayName){
return (‘<tr><td><a href=“‘ + url + ‘”>’+displayName+’</a></td></tr>’);
};
```

I am trying to add the dynamic Link2 between Link1 & Link3 as anchor by placing in between or replace if already exists by addRow function.
My problem is that I can insert in the *tbody* after the *tbody* with *groupstring* but I want to insert in *tbody* one after the blank *tbody*.
Can somebody help modify:

```
 $(‘tbody[groupstring=“%3B%23Application%3B%23”]’).closest(‘tbody’).find(‘td’).each(function(){
```

To access/get the tbody* one after the blank *tbody*?
I even tried:

```
$(‘tbody[groupstring=“%3B%23Application%3B%23”]’).closest(‘tbody’).next(‘tbody’).find(‘td’).each(function(){
```

And

```
$(‘tbody[groupstring=“%3B%23Application%3B%23”]’).closest(‘tbody’).closest(‘tbody’).find(‘td’).each(function()
```

But it did not work.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is there supposed to be an empty `<tbody>` between the first and third?

Comment: Yeah @charlietfl it’s SharePoint list view table.

Comment: So it will always be empty as shown?

Comment: That’s my guess as I saw two different lists and it’s empty. It’s for the space between the list heading and the list. But it might have classes in it but should be blank in html.

Comment: So would need something like `$('tbody[groupstring]').next().next()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('tbody[groupstring]').nextAll('tbody:eq(1)')` should do it.

Demo:

```js
$(function() {
  var $target = $('tbody[groupstring]').nextAll('tbody:eq(1)');
  console.log($target.html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody groupstring="%3B%23Application%3B%23">
    <tr>
      <td>Application</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody></tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="https://link1.com">Link 1</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="https://link3.com">Link 3</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Also note that `groupstring` is not a valid HTML attribute.

Comment: This works! '$(‘tbody[groupstring=“%3B%23Application%3B%23”]’).nextAll(‘tbody:eq(1)’).find(‘tr’).each(function(){'